# how to link drop down list to various text boxes vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have searched everywhere to understand this procedure but nothing has worked so far.

Basically what i want is to link my dropdownlist which is ddlreportid to various textboxes.

Currently, the drop down list is connected to a datasource where it is using the report table to show a list of reportid's e.g 1, 2,3, etc.

What I want to happen is if a user clicks on, say, 1 from the ddlreportid. I want reportname to be placed into txtreportname.text textbox, reportaddress to be placed into txtreportaddress textbox and reportpostcode to be paced into txtreportpostcodec textbox.

Where do I start? If soemone could direct me that would be great.

I have used this code previously but its not working.

```
Protected Sub ddlreportid_SelectedIndexChanged1(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlreportid.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim myConn As New SqlConnection
    Dim myCmd As New SqlCommand


    myConn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString

    myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand

    myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT ReportName, ReportAddress, ReportPostcode WHERE ReportID = @ ReportID"

    myCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ReportID", (ddlreportid.Text)))

    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()

    If (reader.Read()) Then
        txtreportname.Text = reader(0)
        txtreportaddress.Text = reader(1)
        txtreportpostcode.Text = reader(2)

    End If

    myCmd.Dispose()
    myConn.Close()
    myConn.Dispose()

End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try, instead of ...

```
myCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ReportID", (ddlreportid.Text)))
```

... doing this:

```
myCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ReportID", (ddlreportid.SelectedItem.Value)))
```

Also be sure your dropdownlist has `AutoPostBack = "true"` if you want your page to respond immediately.

Comment: Yes AutoPostBack is set to true. I don't have nay errors on the page and runs fine till I select something from the drop down list and comes to this error ' Microsoft JScript runtime error: Member not found.'

Comment: Do I have to put an if statement under page load in relation to autoPostBack?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the HTML that defines the DropDownList and any validators or Javascript you may have that references it. Your error sounds like it's happening on the client side, so we need to see what you have there.

Comment: Regarding page load: In code-behind, AutoPostBack behaves like any other postback.  If you have code that you only want to have run on the first load of the page, wrap it in a `If Not IsPostback ...` clause.

Comment: The HTML code for the dropdownlist is:

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlreportid" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                         DataSourceID="LinqDataSource2" DataTextField="reportID" 
                         DataValueField="reportID">
                     </asp:DropDownList>